# SSL in Python: Why it doesn't send certificate to server?

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509, handshake

I'm writing some software that is supposed to acquire information from SSL-secured web page. Below there's piece of code I use to connect to server.

```
s = socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket (
    s,
    ca_certs = '/home/stilz/Desktop/Certyfikaty/GLOWNE_CA.cer',
    cert_reqs = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
    ssl_version = ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3,
)
ssl_sock.connect ((HOST, PORT))
```

However, this doesn't work. It throws exception with message "Handshake alert failed". I captured some TCP packets that come out of my script and also corresponding packets from Internet Explorer and figured out that my script doesn't send certificate at all (server returns something like "Fatal: no certificate supplied") while IE sends it normally. As far as I know file ca.cer is x509 certificate (beginning with "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----").

Please help me and tell what I'm doing wrong. If I've supplied to few information, please let me know.

Regards

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can update your own question by editing it. You can vote for questions (upvote or downvote) and if you get the answer that satisfies your needs and answers your question, you can mark it as an answer

Comment: Agreed with @Eugene. You could say in the question that it's about using a cert/private key that are on a smartcard, under Windows (if it is under Windows? ... `/home/stilz/Desktop/` doesn't look like it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to determine if you need to authenticate yourself on the server (certificate is sent to the server only in this case) or you need to validate server's authenticity (in which case the certificate is not sent to the server).

Now about issues in your code:

Case 1: you don't need to authenticate on the server. In this case you don't need to specify your certificate and nothing is sent to the server.

Case 2: you need to authenticate yourself on the server. In that case you need to provide your certificate and your private key file in keyfile and certfile parameters. Only then your certificate is sent to the server (and the private key is used in the handshake).

I guess that your have case 1 in fact. So first of all you need to check if the server provides a valid certificate by connecting to it with a web browser and inspecting site's certificate chain. It can happen that the site sends its certificate but omits intermediate CA certificates.

In any case I'd like to remind about the [discussion about certificates in Python docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ssl.html#ssl-certificates) which I suggest you re-read.

Comment: Apparently I didn't read the section you provided. It explains how things work. Now I have to get private key (both certfile and public/private keys are on smartcard). Help would be appreciated (see comments below next post). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the server requests (and requires) a certificate to be sent by the client, you need to supply `ssl.wrap_socket` with the path to *your* certificate (`certfile`) and its matching private key (`keyfile`). The `ca_certs` parameter is only used for the client to verify the server's certificate against known CA certificates, it has nothing to do with sending a client-certificate.

You may need to export your client-certificate and private key from IE (and then convert them to PEM format).

Comment: IE uses smartcard to get key. Is it public or private? As far as I know it's impossible to get private key out of smartcard. Am I right? Anyway, what can I do to export these things from IE? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The smartcard will probably provide both the certificate and the private key. However, it's likely to embed the cryptographic capabilities so that the private key doesn't need to (or can't) leave the smartcard. You probably won't be able to get the private key out in PEM format for `ssl.ssl_wrap` to use. Depending on the interface used by the smart card, it might be worth looking for "PKCS#11" in Python (or whatever the smartcard format is).

Comment: I've tried OpenSC tools (both pkcs11 and pkcs15), but apparently they aren't able to list keys. If IE can do it what I have to do the same? I've tried some USB sniffing (it's USB reader) but I've noticed no traffic.

Comment: Maybe your card isn't PKCS#11-compatible. Try to find out which drivers are used under Windows.

Comment: @stilz It can be OpenSC's impossibility to access the card (this happens with some devices). Is there any particular reason to use Python on Windows? Something more suited for Windows (like .NET) would be able to access the smartcard via CryptoAPI (which is the way IE works).